# How to add multiple ID's into url string PHP loop

Tags: php, arrays, url

I have product ID passed thgrough a URL like so:

```
    if($_POST['purchase']) {

        foreach($cart->get_contents() as $item) {

            $idarray = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < $item['qty']; $i++){

                $sql="INSERT INTO wp_scloyalty_orders VALUES (".$user_id.", ".$item['id'].", NOW())";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);

                $idarray[-----];
            }


            $confpurchase = '?confpurchase=success&id='.$item['id'].''; 

        }

        $cart->empty_cart();

        unset($_SESSION['cart']); 

        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."/my-account".$confpurchase);
        exit;


}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get multiple ID's in the url... I know it will be something to do with looping through and adding each id to an array but I cant get it! Argh.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php), you can create an array:

```
$confpurchase = '...&id[]='.$item['id'].'';
```

However, you should first collect all IDs:

```
$confPurchaseIDs = array();

foreach ($cart->get_contents() as $item)
{
    ...
    $confPurchaseIDs[] = $item['id'];
}
```

And later on process the IDs when you need to create the URL for all IDs.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was thinking of using the implode function to seperate the array with commas, and then using explode the fetch the results on the other side. What do you think?

Comment: As long as IDs are integer values, that's possible as well. I've use the same in some app, this works, too - and keeps the URL length shorter.